# htaccess redirects wrong third-level-domain redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have third-level-domain (domain.example.com) and I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/$1 [L, QSA]
```

So now I need to create folder (name: folder). When I tried to load a page

```
 domain.example.com/folder/index.html
```

the page is not dispayed, I have to load

```
 domain.example.com/domain/folder/index.html...
```

How can I "hide" folder domain so I can load the page via

```
 domain.example.com/folder/index.html
```

Thank you for answers

Comment: And with `[L,QSA]` without space ?

Comment: Your htaccess  adds leading /domain/ to all url. If it is not necessary, delete all lines in htaccess